# How to populate table in C# from database using labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Below is my code to get data from my oracle database to display a table with multiple rows in asp.net(C#). Te columns will be Name, Section and Gender. The headers of the table  are hardcoded, only rows' data should be populated from database. On executing the code, I am getting only 1st row coming from database. Remaining rows are not coming. Please suggest for the solution.

```
public void  GetDailyData()
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dataconn"].ToString()))
        {

            try
            {
                string query = @"SELECT  name,section, gender FROM t_student WHERE order by TRUNC(admissionDate)";               
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);


               DataSet ds = new DataSet();
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               da.Fill(ds);

               foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
               {


                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                   {
                        LabelName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
                       LabelSection.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>(1) ;
                      LabelGender.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>(2) ;


                 }

              }                                                   

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only seeing row data from the first row because that's what you're pulling out when you say `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]` - Rows[0] will always be the first row of the table

This entire block of code is confused;

- you cannot show multiple rows using single labels - Use a Grid component and DataBind it to the datatable.
- The code uses a loop to go through table rows but checks if the table has rows, inside the loop ( the loop won't run if it doesn't) and instead of using the enumerated row it always access the first row on every pass of the loop.
- Do not use a DataSet, just make a new DataTable and fill it - datasets are for when you want to work with multiple related datatables and in this case of a single table are a useless extra layer.
- Do not ExecuteNonQuery on the command, it's a useless operation - the dataadapter will execute the query during the fill, you don't need to do it (and ExecuteNonQuery is for insert/update/delete/create etc - this is a select).

Your code could/should look more like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
gridControl.DataSource = dt;
gridControl.DataBind();
```

That's it. All the rest of the code (apart from the command and connection) should be thrown away